# how can I share spark dataframe across different pytest test functions in a file

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pytest

I am using a fixture to create a spark session to be shared across various pytest tests in a file as follows

'''

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def spark() -> SparkSession:
    builder = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName('we_pipeline_test') \
        .config('spark.ui.showConsoleProgress', 'false') \
        .config('spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields', '200')

    if 'SPARK_MASTER' in os.environ:
        builder = builder.master(os.environ['SPARK_MASTER'])
    else:
        builder = builder.master('local[1]')

    s = builder.getOrCreate()

    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory("we_pipeline") as dir:
        s.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir(dir)
        yield s
        s.stop()
def test_func1(spark):
....
....
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,Schema)
....
.....
'''
```

I need to access this dataframe df in another test function

```
'''
def test_func2(spark):
 df.show()
'''
```

How can a achieve it?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The point is that I need to access the transformations that this dataframe will go through in test_func1 to be accessible in test_func2 and so on.

Comment: While this is contrary to the way tests should be designed , I have provided with an edit a second way that perhaps does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

What you need is to create your dataframe as a fixture too...
In pytest, test functions are meant to be independent,
which means one test should not rely on e.g. the result of another test.

However, if you have a common process that manipulates data and is shared across several test functions,
you can put this into a fixture.
All your test dataframe prep should be done here.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def fixture_data_frame(spark: SparkSession) -> DataFrame:
    data = # Your data here
    schema = # Your schema here
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
    df = df.filter( ... ) # data manipulation

    yield df
```

Then, you can use the fixture_data_frame in your test functions. Since you are probably going to use spark functionality you need the spark SparkSession too:

```
def test_func1(spark, fixture_data_frame):
    # Perform your tests here using the spark session and fixture_data_frame
    assert 1=1 # Perform your testing

def test_func2(spark, fixture_data_frame):
    # Perform other tests here 
    assert 1=1 # Perform your testing
```

EDIT: OP has commented that he would like to actually have the manipulation that has happened in test_func1 available in test_func2 and not as a seperate fixture. While I think design-wise this is wrong this is a way you could approach it.
You can do it by turning the first test into a fixture too and referencing it on the second test.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def test_func1(spark, fixture_data_frame):
    # Perform your manipulations here
    manipulated_df = fixture_data_frame.filter(...)  # example manipulation
    # Perform your tests here
    assert manipulated_df.count() > 0
    yield manipulated_df

def test_func2(spark, test_func1):
    # test_func1 is now both the manipulated data_frame and the test itself.
    # You can perform additional tests here
```

Again it's important to clarify that turning a test into a fixture is somewhat contrary to the common test design principles,
where tests are expected to be independent and should be able to be run in any order.

Comment: I agree tests should ideally be independent. This is a complex parser and its very time consuming to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by wrapping all test functions in a TestClass and creating dataframe as a class variable.